# When to use the abstract factory pattern?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, language-agnostic, factory, factory-pattern

I'm trying to succinctly describe **when** to use a factory, for both myself and my team. I ran across the following related questions, which helped somewhat:

- [When to use factory patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067271/when-to-use-factory-patterns)

  - (useful pdf link is broken)
- [How do you create your Factories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2181269/how-do-you-create-your-factories)

  - (more 'how' rather than 'when')
- [What is your threshold to use factory instead of a constructor to create an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489623/what-is-your-threshold-to-use-factory-instead-of-a-constructor-to-create-an-objec)

  - (some general answers)
- [Factory Pattern. When to use factory methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69849/factory-pattern-when-to-use-factory-methods)

  - (more about factory methods than factory classes)
- [When to use Factory method pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519358/when-to-use-factory-method-pattern)

  - (again more about factory methods)

Based on these links, and a bunch of other sources (listed at the bottom), I've come up with the following:

**When to use the abstract factory pattern:**

- when you use an interface var or the 'new' operator

  - e.g. User user = new ConcreteUserImpl();
- and the code you are writing should be testable / extensible at some point

**Explanation:**

- interfaces by their very nature imply multiple implementations (good for unit testing)
- interface vars imply OCP- and LSP-compliant code (support sub-classing)
- use of the 'new' operator breaks OCP/DI, because highly-coupled classes are hard to test or change

**"Do I create a factory for every object type? That seems excessive."**

- no, you can have one (or a few) factories that produce a lot of (usually related) object types
- e.g. appFactory.createUser(); appFactory.createCatalog(); etc.

**When NOT to use a factory:**

- the new object is very simple and unlikely to be sub-classed

  - e.g. List list = new ArrayList();
- the new object is not interesting to test

  - has no dependencies
  - performs no relevant or long-running work
  - e.g. Logger log = new SimpleLogger();

**References:**

- http://googletesting.blogspot.com/2008/08/where-have-all-singletons-gone.html
- http://misko.hevery.com/2008/07/08/how-to-think-about-the-new-operator/
- http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/17/singletons-are-pathological-liars/
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_Injection
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Closed_Principle
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle

---

My question is: is my summary accurate, and does it make sense? Is there anything I've overlooked?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I hate reviving old threads, but...

I disagree that loggers should be new'd up as above. I often run different loggers in different test environments. I configure the environment to use a specific logger and inject it into objects that log. (I might even inject arrays of loggers.)

Answer (score 5):

I'd also say don't use a factory when you have a particular implementation that you want. To continue the `List` example, I know that I want an `ArrayList` because I'm doing random access. I don't want to rely on a factory getting this right when I can do it myself.

Conversely, when I don't want to know about the concrete subclass then I can use a factory and let it worry about which object to actually instantiate.

I guess I'd suggest that you add a bullet to the "when to use the abstract factory pattern" that says "and you don't really care which concrete subclass you get", and the converse to "when not to use a factory".

EDIT: Be careful to avoid the [general-purpose tool-building factory factory factory](http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?joel.3.219431.12).

Comment: Ok - let's say I wanted the specific advantages of a cached thread pool:
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

However, in my unit tests (for whatever reason) I'm not interested in the results of the work done in the pool, and I don't want to have to wait for the work to finish every time I run my tests. Wouldn't I then still use a factory so I could stub / mock out my thread pool for tests?

It seems to me that when you consider testing, you want to think of **most** of your code as not caring about the actual implementation lest you write untestable code.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Generally most of your code doesn't care about the actual implementation. Choosing between `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` is one of the few times that you do care because they have different performance characteristics. You're right: for testing it's best to ignore the actual implementation as much as possible.

Answer (score 3):

In general, use it when you want to be able to switch of implementation by external configuration.

JDBC and JAXP are excellent examples. For more examples, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673841/examples-of-gof-design-patterns/2707195#2707195).

Comment: Would not that mean to use an IoC container?

Comment: could you please elaborate on when you would use your custom factory vs an IoC for switching object type by config?

Comment: @Max: depends if the API is to be run on an IoC container or not.

Answer (score 1):

Abstract Factory pattern provides with a way to encapsulate concrete factories that share some commonality with each other, meaning they implement same interface/abstract class.

You need to use factory pattern whenever you want to control the initialization of your objects, instead of giving the control to the consumer.